# What does callback stand for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS. I'm studying the following code and I'm wondering what the word callback stands for, what does it?

```
function(fileID, callback) {
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: url + "wishlist/" + fileID,
    type: "GET"
  });

  request.done(callback);

  request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

  }); 
}
```

Comment: It's a parameter, and presumably it's intended to be a function.

Comment: so if the function is used another function is passed as parameter?

Comment: Correct. As in `myFunction(someFileId, function() { alert('done!'); })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't stand for anything, it is not an abbreviation.

In general terms, a callback is a piece of code which is passed to a function to be executed at a later time.

In JavaScript, that "piece of code" is almost always a function.

The simplest example of such is `setTimeout` where the first argument is the code (which should be a function but may be a string to be evalulated) and the second argument is the number of milliseconds from now that the "later time" occurs at.

```
function aFunction () { alert("Ta da"); }
setTimeout( aFunction /* The callback function */,
            500 /* 500ms from now */ 
          );
```

In the example you give in the question, the "later time" is "When the response to the HTTP request has been received". Another example might be "When the user clicks on a link":

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', aFunction);
```

See also: [the Wikipedia entry on callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 4):

Callback is the function invoked when the response returns from the server.

Comment: In this case it is. A callback is a function that gets executed once the function is completed